# Display contents from multiple subfolders

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, document-library

I am using SharePoint 2010's Form WebPart in junction with its Document Library WebPart.

The form is currently filtering results from a Document Library called Fruit (which is also being displayed with the Document Library WebPart).

In Fruit, there are three subfolders: Produce, Pies, and Prices. For some reason, the form query only parses one folder/list at a time--which is whatever directory I have clicked (be it Fruit or the 3 subfolders).

My goal is to type in "Apple" as a query and search, then have the "Apple" document from each folder (Produce, Pies, Prices) be displayed. Is there a way to do this, and if so, is it a (relatively) simple fix?